# Javascript exit function with return from another function

Tags: javascript, function, return

A better understanding is by code. Let say I have the function bellow:

```
const firstFct = function() {
    if(!valid) {
        return 'error...';
    }

    return ...
}
```

I want to exit **firstFct** using a second function. Instead of using that **if** .

```
const secondFct = function(value, msg) {
    if(!value) {
        return msg;
    }
}

const firstFct = function() {
    secondFct(valid, "error"); // this should exit **firstFct** only if !value

    return ...
}
```

Not sure if there's a way to achieve this with **return**.

Comment: Check the return value of `secondFct`?

Comment: Then i'm back to same situation.

Comment: Return is scoped to the current function. Just return some value from secondFct and check that in firstFct...

Comment: This is what exception are for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the result of the first call to distinguish a result from an error for an early exit.

```
const firstFct = function() {
    if (!valid) {
        return { error: 'error...' };
    }
    return ...
}

const firstFct = function() {
    var temp = secondFct(valid, "error");

    if (temp && typeof temp === 'object' && 'error' in temp) {
        return temp.error;
    }
    return ...
}
```

Or use an [exception handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and throw an error.

Comment: This way i don't avoid that **if** . Can't throw the error either because I need to end the server response

Comment: the return statment need an if. it is not possible to use it in an conditional operator or with an logical AND/OR, because these are expressions and `return` does not work with expressions to trigger that.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: does it help, or do you need some more information or an other answer?

Comment: It's okay i got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need to separate between 2 different logics:

- decide *if* to do AKA data validation
- decide *what* to do AKA app flow

In other words: don't let `secondFct` to also decide if it's valid, *and* throw the error message.

Consider this:

```
const isValid = function(data) {
  //some checks...
  return flag; // true OR false
}

const app = function() {
  // ...
  if (isValid(data)) {
    // handle error
    return 'error ...'
  }

  return ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Well here a possible solution. Although I would not recommend it.

(I would recommend Nina Scholz Version)

```
function myFunction() {myFunction:{
    console.log('i get executed');
    break myFunction;
    console.log('i do not get executed');
}}
```

Now with this pricinple you could do:

```
const firstFct = function() {myScope: {
    secondFct(valid, "error") ? break myScope: null;
}};
```

Now if you return a truthy value the execution is suspended, else it continues. 
I know this is not 100% what you wanted, but it is as good as it gets.

Alternatively you can throw an error, which will suspend the JavaScript Execution. 
I also do not recommend this.

Generally, we might be able to help you a bit better for a more sophisticated example. 
There might be another solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response